# Explore the conditions under which the measures of two angles in a triangle are kept to be constants

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given A,C are two points on DP and DQ of  $\triangle DPQ$, B is the intercept of AQ and CP, PQ=AP+CQ,  $\angle \alpha+\angle \beta=180^o$.  If also given  AP=CQ, it can be proven $\angle PDQ$ = 60$^o$ and $\angle PBQ$=120$^o$.

Question:

If the requirement of  AP=CQ removed, are there any other conditions that   can lead to the same conclusion  $\angle PDQ$ = 60$^o$ and $\angle PBQ$=120$^o$?

It seems that we need to construct something to link PQ,AP and CQ together, need help to continue.

[image]

Comment: in quadrilateral $ABCD$, the sum of the interior angles = ?

Comment: You are absolutely right,  modify the question to find the measures of the two angles.

Comment: A couple of quick remarks: $DABC$ is cyclic by definition, so in particular $\angle PDQ + \angle PBQ = 180^\circ$ so it suffices to find one of them. A quick sketch in Geogebra seems to give that $\angle PDQ = 60^\circ$. A natural construction which comes to mind is to consider the point $E$ on $PQ$ such that $PA = PE$ (and immediately $QE = QC$), but I haven't explored the properties of this construction. Maybe also take a look at Miquel's theorem and complete quadrilaterals for inspiration?

Comment: Geogebra seems to me to indicate that it isn't a fixed value. (I did in fact set a point on $PQ$ which was generating two circles around $P$ and $Q$ for the purpose of fixing $A$ and $C$ for an arbitrary $D$).

Comment: @Joffan, thanks for the check. I found if  AP=CQ, following your thought,  we have one unique answer of $60^o$ and $120^o$. Then, my question will be : are there any other configurations give the same answer?

Comment: @dodtukoz I’m afraid the condition will lead back to AP=CQ, unless can be proved otherwise.

Comment: Although a bit trivial, $\angle APB + \angle BQC = 60^\circ$ leads to the conclusion.

Comment: @dodtukoz I was thinking about some scenarios that do not lead to  AP=CD , but still give the same measures. However, the way the question is framed, I agree with your point.  If you can prove PB=BQ gives AP=CD, it’s an acceptable answer. Can you?

Comment: @Tanny, that’s a really nice one -:)! I am thinking about AB=BC ( not equivalent to PB=BQ, I think). Still struggling to prove it either way.

Comment: You draw two circles in which PQ a cord - one with $120^0$ view of PQ and the other with $60^0$ view. With any points picked on those arcs you may create triangles where I think the conditions you request hold.

Comment: @Bright Was my suggestion clear enough or you need an answer?

Comment: @Moti,  Thanks, that would be great! Do you have $\alpha+\beta=180^\circ$ and PA+PC=PQ in your consideration?

Comment: No. For a given PQ I am building the Locus of points that will result a structure in which $\alpha+\beta=180^0$. Is this what you are looking for? By the way, a side benefit is finding the "center" of an equilateral triangle with just 3 circles and one line (typical solution requires 4 circles and 2 lines).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please illustrate in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution assumes some basic knowledge.

[image]

Let me know if this is what you have in mind and if all is clear.

Comment: Thanks!   This is very clear.  Looking at your plot, it seems like AB=BC,  should that also leads to the desired angles?  My original figure was not plotted proportionally.

Comment: B selection is arbitrary.